# Exception thrown while running JMockit tests through ant script

Tags: ant, jmockit

I am trying to run JMcokit tests using ant script. But I am getting exceptions. I have tried to include java agent using 'jvmargs' as mentioned in other posts, also tried to add jmockit jar before junit jar in the classpath, but its of no use.
If I add java agent argument in my eclipse, then I am able to run them through eclipse, but not through ant script.
The only way I am able to run them through ant script is by adding attach.dll in my java path. But that is not a feasible solution and need a work around.

Ant script:

```
    <!-- Run the TestSuite -->
            <junit fork="yes" description="Runs the Junit testcase." printsummary="yes"
                haltonfailure="${halt.on.junit.failure}" showoutput="yes">

                 <sysproperty key="java.library.path" path="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_12/jre/bin/attach.dll"/>  

                <jvmarg value="-javaagent:${lib.dir}/jmockit.jar" />

                <jvmarg value=" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"/>


            <!--    <classpath path="${lib.dir}/jmockit-0.999.8.jar" />
                <classpath path="${lib.dir}/junit-4.7.jar" />-->


                <classpath>
                    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/jmockit-0.999.8.jar" />
                    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/junit-4.7.jar" />
                    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/activemq-all-5.5.1.jar" />
                    <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
                    <!--<fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                        <include name="**/*.jar" />
                        <exclude name="**/jmockit-0.999.8.jar, **/junit-4.7.jar" />
                    </fileset>-->
                </classpath>


                <!-- <test name="com.quest.shareplex.hadoopconnector.junits.AllTests" 
                    fork="no" todir="${junit.output.dir}"> <formatter type="xml" /> </test> -->

                <batchtest fork="no" todir="${junit.output.dir}">
                    <formatter type="xml" />
                    <fileset dir="${connector.src}">
                        <include name="**/*Test.java" />
                        <exclude name="**/*HDFSUtilsTest*.java" />
                    </fileset>
                </batchtest>

            </junit>
```

Please let me know, if there is any other way to work it, or if I am doing something incorrectly.
I have tried all the ways that are mentioned on stack overflow:
-Tried to change java lib path
-Tried to change java class path
-Added java agent
But nothing is working.

Exception:

```
<error type="java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException">java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
</error>
  <system-out><![CDATA[]]></system-out>
  <system-err><![CDATA[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no attach in java.library.path
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load Java agent; please add lib/tools.jar from your JDK to the classpath
    at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:82)
    at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgent(JDK6AgentLoader.java:54)
    at mockit.internal.startup.AgentInitialization.initializeAccordingToJDKVersion(AgentInitialization.java:21)
    at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfNeeded(Startup.java:203)
    at org.junit.runner.Runner.<clinit>(Runner.java:25)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:13)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.<init>(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:31)
    at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.<init>(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:473)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeInVM(JUnitTask.java:1420)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:848)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1899)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:800)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
```

Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your java is plain jre.

> java.library.path java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load Java
>   agent; please add lib/tools.jar from your JDK to the classpath
>       at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:82)
>       at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgent(JDK6AgentLoader.java:54

Jmockit needs **JDK** to work.

Comment: But how do we do it using ant script, as we need it to work on every other machine.

Comment: every machine you need to have jdk.  Have you considered CI like jenkins? They can automate deployments including jdk.

Comment: @Jayan +1 this fixed my project. For some reason it defaulted to jre6 instead of the workspace default (jdk6).

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Mac, this is happening because the forked JVM doesn't have tools.jar in the classpath.  I encountered this today and [blogged about it](http://www.selikoff.net/2013/11/16/upgrading-to-mavericks-eclipse-java-fix-jmockit/).